# Php Setting File permissions for OrangeHrm in Ubuntu system

Tags: deployment, ubuntu

I am trying to deploy OrangeHrm in Ubuntu Server but getting the following errors..


Component   Status

PHP version     OK (ver 5.3.3)

MySQL Client    OK (ver 5.1.52)

MySQL Server    OK (ver 5.1.52)

MySQL InnoDB Support    Enabled

Write Permissions for "lib/confs"   Not Writeable*

Write Permissions for "lib/logs"    Not Writeable*

Write Permissions for "symfony/config"  Not Writeable*

Write Permissions for "symfony/apps/orangehrm/config"   Not Writeable*

Write Permissions for "symfony/cache"   Not Writeable*

Write Permissions for "symfony/log"     Not Writeable*

Maximum Session Idle Time before Timeout    OK

Register Globals turned-off     OK

Memory allocated for PHP script     OK

Web server allows .htaccess files   OK
* Web server requires write privilege to the following directory

I have changed the file accessing permission as
"sudo chmod 777 orangehrm" and the folder is in 777 mode, still the errors exist.
Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

For me it helped to change the the owner of the corresponding directory to *www-data*:

- Go to the directory your web page data is in (usually *`/var/www/YOUR_SITE_NAME`*):
   `cd /var/www/YOUR_SITE_NAME`
- Change the owner to *www-data*: 
  `sudo chown -R www-data .` 
   Alternatively, you can change the group, too e.g. to you username's group, in order to be able to access the files from you account: 
  `sudo chown -R www-data:YOUR_USERNAME .` 
   Note that in both cases the *dot* at the end of the command is part of the command!

Answer (score 0):

you should include -R in your command, like :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 orangehrm
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting all folders to 777 for a web facing site. Run something like the following from your orangehrm folder;

```
sudo chmod 760 lib/confs lib/logs symfony/config symfony/apps/orangehrm/config symfony/cache symfony/log
```

That will give you read/write/execute for the owner and then read/write for the group and then no permissions for all others.

Then make sure the owner of the orangehrm folder is your web user ie, www-data

I would suggest confirming the permissions for those folders with the orangehrm forum.

ie, http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2531&p=3452&hilit=chmod&sid=e53a96e31a32ce4cbfa7998f43fdfc95#p3452